# Servlet Wrong response

Tags: java, xml, servlets, web-applications

I have 3 servlets in my web application.

The first servlet is workinh OK.
The second and third servlet which is copying from the first one, doesn't work and doesn't get response.

However, I search on internet and all websites say: `the error in web.xml file`

This is my `web.xml` file:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <web-app version="3.1">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>getmarks</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>getmarks</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Login</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Enter</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Enter</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>getmarks</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/getmarks</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Enter</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Enter</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Comment: What are the names of servlets which doesn't work? Any errors in logs? Where is code for not working Servlets? Just saying , **not working** is not enough.

Comment: Login and Enter not response
however ( Login and Enter ) are copy of getmarks servlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Try This Code Web.xml file 



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
      <display-name>Your Project Name</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ABC</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>getmarks</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DEF</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Login</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>GHI</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Enter</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ABC</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/getmarks_1</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DEF</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Login_1</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>GHI</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Enter_1</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    </web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put full class names in the `<servlet-class>` tag.

Also, `<web-app>` tag is missing some attributes about XML Schema. You can find more information [here](http://www.mkyong.com/web-development/the-web-xml-deployment-descriptor-examples/).

For version 3.1 it should look like this:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

// your mappings 

</web-app>
```

Closing `</web-app>` tag is also missing.

Comment: yes i put this , but this isn't the real rong , thanks .

Comment: @HasanEdrees You should provide more information. Can you edit the question to include servlet classes?